# Distributing database with Android app

Tags: android

I have an Android app which uses an SQLite database of 3MB.  If I distribute this in the assets folder and then copy it to data, I will end up with 2 copies at a cost of 6MB.

Is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host the information on a server and then, on the initial startup of the application, grab the necessary data.  It probably isn't the solution you are looking for but it will work.

Comment: Fortunately (or unfortunately), Haphazard is right. And there's a slight alternative solution, if you could bundle the minimum posible db that will enable some basic funtionality in your app and tell the user that not everything will work until the rest of the DB is downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for that Haphazard, I will do that.  Does anyone have any sample code to download the DB on the initial startup?

Comment: @NiMuSi I don't.  You will have more luck if you post a new question asking for guidance on that topic.